# Can't get URxvt to work with the font "Inter". Using it causes spaces in-between letters

Tags: fonts, rxvt, x-resources

I cannot get the popular Google font "Inter" to work with URxvt. When I set the font, `xrdb -merge .Xresources` and open a new terminal, it has spaces between the letters `l i k e t h i s`. Suggestions on Google point to `URxvt.letterSpace: -1`, but this doesn't do anything. Also, I don't need to use this for my other working fonts.

I know Inter works because it's installed on my system and I am using it in my top panel.

I know other fonts are working in URxvt, specifically `UbuntuMono Nerd Font Mono` and `Noto Sans Mono`.

In my .Xresources it looks like this: `URxvt.font: xft:Inter: size=13`. I tried things like `Inter-regular`, `Inter: style=regular`, but nothing works.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. There is nothing special or fancy about the Inter font.

Comment: Consider display the entire contents of your `.Xresources` so that we can run it on our system and cause your error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font rendering issue in urxvt -- too much space between characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118641/font-rendering-issue-in-urxvt-too-much-space-between-characters)

Comment: That does not solve my issue. I read that post beforehand and tried all solutions in there.

All I have my in my .Xresouces is URxvt.*termName: rxvt-unicode-256color, URxvt*imLocale: en_US.UTF-8 and then my font.

I ran fc-match "Inter" and received "Inter-Regular.ttf: "inter" "Regular". I tried all these and different combinations in my .Xresources, but the letter spacing remains.